# О значении диалектных слов

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, диалекты

Заборинка, худой ветер, разливка (теста).

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Разливка — слово, распространённое донельзя, не из диалектных. Вполне может соотносится и с поломником, большой ложкой. Представление о худом ветре, как о средстве очевидно скверном и даже убийственном, встречается в заговорах. Заборинка — часто встречающийся топоним. Есть посёлки, районы и город в Новгородской области. С понятным отношением: сразу около соснового леса.

Answer (score 1):

- *Разливка* может иметь несколько значений:

  1. Разливательная ложка (Уральское);
  2. Посуда для приготовления теста, квашня (Вологодское);
  3. Глубокая глиняная плошка для кипячения молока (Ярославское).

Стало быть, вам интересно второе.

- *Худой ветер* — значит *плохой*. Наверняка это можно связать с прилагательными *сильный*, *холодный* и т. п., ведь именно такой ветер обычно называют плохим.

Вообще, *худой* в значении *плохой* — довольно распространенное являение в диалектах (Архангельская, Волгоградская, Калужская, Рязанская и др. области).

Для [иллюстрации](http://search2.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=dialect&sort=gr_tagging&req=%F5%F3%E4%EE%E9):

> Бывает, что снятся к худой погоде: зимой, дак к морозу да к погоде, летом― дак к дождю. [Обычаи. Похороны. Часть 2 (Архангельская область, 1996)]

- С *заборинкой* посложней. Возможно, слово как-то связано с глаголом [*забирать*](http://slovar-dalja.ru/slovar-dalya/zabirat/8137/) (с добавлением суффикса *ин* или *инк*). Точного значения я не нашел ни в одном из известных мне словарей.

*При ответе использовались данные ["Словаря русский народных говоров"](http://www.slovorod.ru/dia-all-russian-folk/index.html).*